# Where can one download Bitcoin Days Destroyed data? Alternately where to get data to calculate BDD?

Tags: raw-data, bitcoin-days-destroyed

I'm trying to find a source of downloadable (preferably csv) data for Bitcoin Days Destroyed. Alternately I can calculate it myself provided I can find the constituent data.

In particular, I want to calculate dormancy which is total number of days destroyed  divided by volume. I know the total number of days destroyed is the value of the transaction multiplied by the number of days since that BTC was last moved.

Where can I find either data that has already been calculated for dormancy, or data on days destroyed, or barring either of those, the number of days since the last transaction for each Bitcoin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bitcoin Days Destroyed data you can for example go there https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/charts/coindays-destroyed?interval=3m you can download the data they used in .csv

https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/ does a pretty good job at providing useful data, charts about the bitcoin blockchain

If you want to compute and made your own calculation yourself the best way would be to download the full blockchain 250giga+ with bitcoin core https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin and use a tool like Abe https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe to configure how the data are treated